# Vista Preview antes de crear la publicacion laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-7

Estoy tratando de hacer una Preview antes de crear mi publicacion, Quiero tener dos botones al final de llenar mi formulario, Preview y crear, la funcionalidad de preview seria una vista previda de como se veria mi publicacion antes de crearla, y queria saber como puedo aplicar esta funcionalidad

ya que me gustaría que el usuario viera como se vera su publicacion antes de crearla

no se si me explique de la mejor manera

```
  public function previewproperties(Request $reuqest)
    {
        
        $properti = new Propertie;

        $detail = new Detail;

        $detail->antiquity = $request->antiquity;
        $detail->furnished = $request->furnished;
        $detail->floor = $request->floor;


        $properti->details_id = $detail->id;
        $properti->name = $request->name;
        $properti->code = $request->code;
        $properti->price = $request->price;
        $properti->description = $request->description;

        $properti->departaments_id = $request->departaments;
        $properti->municipalities_id = $request->municipalities;

        $properti->property_type_id = $request->type_property;
        $properti->offer_type_id = $request->type;

        $properti->details_id = $detail->id;

        $properti->lat = $request->lat;
        $properti->lng = $request->lng;
        $properti->address = $request->address;

        if($request->hasfile('images'))
        
        { 
            $i = 1;
                foreach($request->file('images') as $item_img ){  
                    
                    $img = new Image;
                    $ext = $item_img->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting extension
                    $newFile = $properti->id . '-' . time().'-'.$i.'.' .$ext; // changing file name to property id + current time stemp + esxtension.
                    $item_img->move('images',$newFile);
                    
                    $img->name = $newFile;
                    $img->property_id = $properti->id;
            $i++;
                        
                };
        }        
    
        $piso_id = $properti->id;
        
        $space = new Space;
        $space->property_id = $piso_id;
        $space->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms;
        $space->bathrooms = $request->bathrooms;
        $space->parking = $request->parking;
        $space->area = $request->area;
        $properti->spaces_id = $space->id;

        foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {

            $charc = new Characteristic;
            $charc->property_id = $piso_id;
            $charc->characteristic = $characteristic;

        }
    
        
    return view('properties.preview',compact('properti','space','piso_id','charc'));
    }
```

Ruta

```
  Route::get('/preview','PropertyController@previewproperties');
```

Comment: lo acabo de editar no se si me explique mejor

Comment: Lo que tengo en el controlador que publique, pero no se si estoy en lo correcto